# How can I change the appearance of a Winforms TreeView SelectedNode using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can set the Treeview selected node using code, but it's appearance does not change.

```
 TreeNode selectedNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
 TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode("I am new");
 selectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
 treeView1.SelectedNode = newNode;
```

When I select nodes using my mouse the background color and fore colors change. I want the same thing to happen when I select a node using code. How can I change the appearance of a Winforms TreeView SelectedNode using C#? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set [`HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection.aspx) to `false`? For some reason the default value is `true` which will prevent the nodes from appearing selected unless the control has focus (which it of course will have when nodes are seleced using the mouse).